# Jquery Hide & Show IMG - Toggle Functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following piece of HTML and jQuery but its not working properly:

**HTML**

```
<div class="conversationsMessage">
    <img src="images/conversations-message-control-pin.png" id="conversationsMessagePin" class="conversationsMessagePin" />
    <img src="images/conversations-message-control-pin-active.png" id="conversationsMessagePinActive" class="conversationsMessagePin" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('img.conversationsMessagePin').click(function() {
    alert('yep here now...');
    if ($('img#conversationsMessagePinActive', this).css('display') == 'none') {
        alert('1');
        $(this).hide();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePin', $(this).closest('div.conversationsMessage')).show();
    } else {
        alert('2');
        $(this).hide();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePinActive', $(this).closest('div.conversationsMessage')).show();
    }
});
```

The problem is it always shows alert '2' - eg: the if statement always equates to false. I have also tried the following - with different if statement:

```
$('img.conversationsMessagePin').click(function() {
    alert('yep here now...');
    if ($('img#conversationsMessagePin', this).is(':visible')) {
        alert('1');
        $(this).hide();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePin', $(this).closest('div.conversationsMessage')).show();
    } else {
        alert('2');
        $(this).hide();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePinActive', $(this).closest('div.conversationsMessage')).show();
    }
});
```

Neither currently works - can someone give me a tip on what I'm doing wrong here..

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`$('img#conversationsMessagePin', this)` - the second parameter is the context, where you want to find something. In this function 'this' - it's a `$('img.conversationsMessagePin')`. You are searching img in img and it's always wrong. You need something like this `$('img#conversationsMessagePin', $(this).closest('div.conversationsMessage'))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to check if your image `#conversationsMessagePin` is visisble:

```
if ($('img#conversationsMessagePin').is(':visible'))
```

Although I think there are other problems in your code.

Here is one way to toggle the images showing:

```
$('img.conversationsMessagePin').click(function() {
    alert('yep here now...');
    if ($('img#conversationsMessagePin').is(':visible')) {
        alert('1');
        $('img#conversationsMessagePin').hide();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePinActive').show();
    } else {
        alert('2');
        $(this).hide();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePin').show();
        $('img#conversationsMessagePinActive').hide();
    }
});​
```

Or even better:

```
$('.conversationsMessagePin').on('click', function() {
    $('.conversationsMessagePin').toggle();
});​
```

This last answer assumes you have one image hidden and one showing to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.` which is a class selector:

```
if ($('img.conversationsMessagePin').is(':visible'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to evaluate the style attribute of an element with no style attribute.

So, to solve your problem, you can set that attribute in any of these ways:

1.`$('img#conversationsMessagePinActive').css('display', 'none');` before your if statement

2.`$('img#conversationsMessagePinActive').hide();` before your if statement

3.`<img src="images/conversations-message-control-pin-active.png" id="conversationsMessagePinActive" class="conversationsMessagePin" style="display:none;"/>`